# Azure Self hosted IR running slow

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a problem in self hosted IR which is running slow.
Although i had a check on CPU and memory usage which is fine in ADF.
Please let me know to overcome the issue.

Answer (score -2):

To overcome the issue you need to first identify the issue.

You can gather the self-hosted IR logs.  For a self-hosted IR, you can upload logs that are related to the failed activity or all logs on the self-hosted IR node.

- On the Monitor page for the service UI, select Pipeline runs.
- Under Activity runs, in the Error column, select the highlighted button to display the activity logs, as shown in the following screenshot:

[image]

- Select `Send logs`.

Later you can go through the [Copy activity performance and scalability guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance)  to improve the performance of the activity.

Comment: This should really be a comment (pointing to the guide), not an answer, as this is only explaining how to troubleshoot. Impossible to know the root cause of the OP's performance at this point.